# A/B/C testing evaluation over time ans across groups

Tags: multivariate-analysis, sql

I'm needing to validate an inherited testing project correct use of confidence testing.

Direct mail creatives are being evaluated at month end over a 90 day campaign cycle for several unique customer groups (eg.: new, upgraded, lapsed, etc.) Here's a low volume data example for just one customer group (new) for a single month (Note, the eval process repeats for the next 2 months as the #mail & %Resp(onse) accumulates):

```
Treatment       #Mail #Response %Resp  Z-score  
---------       ----- --------- ------  -------  
Control          182    35      19.23%   N/A  
Treatment A      180    45      25.00%  1.33  
Treatment B      189    28      14.81% -1.13  
Treatment C      188    61      32.45%  2.94
```

The question (s):

1. Is this the most appropriate (single tail) test given required assumptions for normality & randomness of the data?
2. 'Treatment C' w/ a Z-score of 2.94 suggests a 95% confident lift over Control for month 1, declines to non-significance in month 2, but then reverts back to 95% confidence level in month 3.  Should 'Treatment C' be considered the NEW control for the upcoming next quarter?
3. Now assuming a dissimilar performance for 'Treatment C' is also observed across the other remaining customer groups (upgraded, lapsed, etc.) during the same monthly eval process over the quarter, how should the analyst use that finding comparatively in determining whether 'Treatment C' should be used at all for the new customer group?
4. Is there a less error prone/subjective approach to solving this problem of what alternative creative should become the new control within and across groups over time?
5. Based on #4 above, is their a simple library or query example one can implement this within MySQL versus currently within Excel?